# Reasons for rejected edit make no sense

Tags: discussion, support, rejected-edits, specific-edit

Here's the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20340818%22Edit%20review%20details%22)
OP was asking about an "update" button in Visual Studio Code, but he was referring to "Synchronize Changes" button per [Visual Studio Code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol#_git-status-bar-actions), which IMO was making the question confusing, and almost impossible to find in search results, so I changed that, and added a small screenshot.

The Edit was rejected with 1 Approve and 2 Reject votes. Reasons for rejection:

> This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.

It's definitely not an answer. Should I comment "please update your question" instead of editing?

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

That's completely untrue; the purpose of my edit was to make it easier to find and more accurate.

I'm a new user and am still learning to use Stack Overflow. What should I do in cases like this?

Comment: How can you know op meant this button? Maybe they meant a button from some extension that is really called "update"?

Comment: @BDL in the comment, the OP gives a screenshot of that button (I think it's that button, I don't really know the tech). If it is indeed that, Braca, then you should have made it clearer you were integrating the OP's comment in the post. Without that it makes it look like you decided that was what the OP meant

Comment: @Patrice My Edit summary "Comment: Corrected the name of the button, and added a picture for clarification"

Comment: Ah ok. In this case you **have to** mention in the edit description that these changes come from a comment. When you only look at the edit it sounds as if you changed the question and made the picture yourself. The text you wrote says what you did, but not why and where this information comes from.

Comment: @Braca indeed. How can I, as a reviewer, know you meant "the OP said this was the button he used and pointed me to the screenshot", instead of "I know the tech, I think it's what the OP is using, and took a screenshot myself"?

Comment: I think "Clearly conflicts with the author's intent" would have been a better reject reason since then it would have been clearer that they thought you were changing the question instead of clarifying it. But it's important to remember that we can't see the comments on a question when we're reviewing suggested edits.

Comment: @Patrice please check comments, user provided the screenshot

Comment: @BSMP Thanks, I wasn't aware of that

Comment: @Braca **I know**, I was the first one to say so in the comment chain here.... What I'm telling you, is that when I review an edit, I do not see these comments, so unless you make it clear where you took your information, it looks like you just came up with this yourself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While it is a bit of a gamble when you are making drastic changes to a post, your only hope is the reviewers read your edit comment:

> Corrected the name of the button, and added a picture for clarification

Oh, sure, yes, that is what you did. Which I kind of see in the diff I'm looking at.

Maybe it is better to make explicit where you got that screenshot from and why those other changes are needed:

> The OP provided a screenshot in the comments which I now move in the question for them and based on the screenshot I corrected the name of the button as that button isn't labelled update.

When I see such edit comment I check the post and verify if the comments are there, if everything of value has been edited in and then accept the edit.

This outcome isn't guaranteed. When editors see large(-ish) parts of the post edited with new content being added they are more likely to reject it.

Alternatively you could have left a comment for the OP asking them to edit their post to include that screenshot and adapt the wording. Do note that the comment box accepts `[edit]` as a shortcut for rendering a link that allows the OP  to edit their post (in case they weren't aware of the edit link under their post).

Comment: Thanks. You're right. The fact that after spending counties hours learning about how SO works, and still finding it more difficult to deal with than pointers, unaligned memory or stuff like that probably means I should just give up, and do something useful instead

Comment: @Braca yeah, the suggested-edit queue has a problem of too many robo-reviewers. Do know that some chatrooms have users around with edit-privileges so if you have something that you're unsure of if it gets through if you edit it, feel free to call for help of those higher reps. You don't have to fix SO all by yourself ....

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was just too impatient, it's time for SO cool-down for me